# Access pass.json content from PKPass

Tags: ios, json, passkit

I download a .pkpass file from a server and create a `PKPass` instance with the file. 
In the .pkpass file is a json file called pass.json. In this json file is a key named "barcode" I tried to use `[pass localizedValueForFieldKey:@"barcode"];` but it returns nil.

Am I doing something wrong or how can I read content of a .pkpass file aka `PKPass`

Thank you for reading.